# Discord.py swear word filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, filter, discord.py

I'm making a discord.py bot with rewrite. I want to make an anti-swear word filter so that if someone swears in a message it will delete the message and send a message. I have a swear word file with all the words that I need.

This is the code that I have so far, but it doesn't work:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx, message):
    msg = message.content
    with open('badWords.txt') as BadWords:
        if msg in BadWords.read():
            await message.delete()
            await ctx.send("Dont use that word!")
        else:
            await ctx.process_commands(message)
```

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's assume that `BadWords.txt` is formatted like this:

```
Word1 Word2 Word3
```

Note that every word is separated by a space.

So, we need to open the file, outside the `on_message()` function. If it's inside the function, then we would open it all the time, every time. That can be hard on the bot. So, at the top, below the `import` statements:

```py
with open('BadWords.txt', 'r') as f:
    words = f.read()
    badwords = words.split()
```

Now, you have all the words, in an array named `badwords`. Go into your `on_message()` function, and add this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx, message):
    msg = message.content
    for word in badwords:
        if word in msg:
            await message.delete()
            await ctx.send("Dont use that word!")
    await ctx.process_message(message)
```

Comment: What does the `process_message` do?

Comment: @BhavyadeepYadav The `process_message()` method is there to allow commands to be executed with the same message. If that is not there, only the `on_message()` event's code will be executed.

Comment: Thanks! :D This helped me answer other questions with the same problem.

Comment: Awesome! I did `.splitlines()` instead of `split()`, so that it only splits per line and not in the middle of words (because the default is any whitespace).

Answer (score 1):

```
async def on_message(ctx, message):
    msg = message.content
    with open('badWords.txt') as BadWords:
        if msg in BadWords.read():
            await message.delete()
            await ctx.send("Dont use that word!")
    await ctx.process_commands(message)
```

`await ctx.process_commands(message)` allows you to use commands after the `on_message` was used.

Comment: The code is ill-formed due to bad indentation, please fix it. Also what if ```msg in BadWords.read()``` is false? Then ```await ctx.process_commands(message)``` will not execute.

Answer (score -3):

Discord bots with `Administrator permissions` `(permission integer '8')` have the same permissions as a regular user. Since no user can `delete` another user's messages, bots can't do this either. For this reason, a bot also can't `edit` other user's messages.

Comment: This is not entirely true. If you look [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.delete) in discord.py's documentation, bots are able to delete messages.

Comment: Bots with `Administrator Permissions (8)` have the same permissions that Administrators in a server would have. As Administrators can delete other people's messages, so can bots with this given permission. These bots can also view all channels (even those hidden to most members), and do other things that other HUMAN MEMBERS with this permission can do.